# How monadicIO works

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, io-monad

I have the following code

```
fastShuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
fastShuffle a = <some code>

prop_fastShuffle_correct :: [Int] -> Property
prop_fastShuffle_correct s =  
  monadicIO ( do
    sh <- run (fastShuffle s) 
    return ( True ==> ( insertionSort sh == insertionSort s  && 
                        if length s > 10 
                          then s /= sh 
                          else True ) ) )
```

And .. it is working. I can't understand how what looks to be a pure function (`prop_fastShuffle_correct`) can call a non pure function that has side effects (`fastShuffle`).

Hope that someone can explain.

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know QuickCheck very well, but looking at the definition of `Property`, it looks like `Property` includes a constructor which stores an `IO` value.

Comment: There are several types in the libraries that internally use `IO` in their definition. Because of that, they can allow a function like `monadicIO`, taking an `IO` action and returning the library type. QuickCheck's `Property` is one of these types: it has to use `IO` in its (opaque) definition, otherwise QuickCheck could never test IO actions like your `fastShuffle`.

Comment: you should include all your import statements to make the code complete and reproducible on its own.

Answer (score 4):

Functions in Haskell never have side effects.

There are only *values* with side effects, like `getLine` (which is a value, not a function). `getLine` is the instruction "read a line of text from standard in". It's not a function that executes the instruction, it *is* the instruction.

And `putStrLn` is not a function which writes text to standard out. `putStrLn` is a function, which takes a string as a parameter, and returns an instruction to write that string to standard out.

There is no problem with storing these instructions in pure data structures. If you want to actually *execute* them, however, then at some point they must be part of the main program value `main`.

Comment: I wish all monads answers were like that.

Comment: @WillNess this actually isn't a monad thing, it's an `IO` thing. `List`, for example, is a monad, but list values *aren't* actions.

Comment: the separation of computation and calculation (evaluation) *is* a monad thing (well, actually, a functor thing). nondeterministic computations just happen to be modeled by pure `[]` calculations. a value `[1,2] :: [Int]` is (taken to be) an instruction for "nondeterministically produce a value which is either `1` or `2`" (by this interpretation), just like `return 1 :: IO Int` is an instruction for <the obvious thing>.