# List with first value from IO

Tags: haskell, io, monads, io-monad

I've created an infinite list whose first element takes a little while to generate:

```
slowOne = do
  threadDelay (10 ^ 6)
  return 1

infiniteInts :: [IO Integer]
infiniteInts = loop slowOne
where
  loop :: IO Integer -> [IO Integer]
  loop ioInt = ioInt : loop (fmap (+1) ioInt)
```

When I print the list, I can observe the delay occuring not only at the first element but at *all* the elements:

```
main =
  mapM_
      (\ioInt -> do
        i <- ioInt
        print i
      )
    infiniteInts
```

I'm trying to improve my intuition about IO: Why is there a delay for each element, not only for the first that's generated with `slowOne`?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is surprising. `fmap f i`, for an `IO` action `i`, is an action that does exactly the same as `i` but applies `f` to the result. That "exactly the same" here obviously includes the delay, and it's not clear to me why you were surprised by this.

Comment: @RobinZigmond: In another language the results of an action might be cached. It's great that all this is not surprising to you, but I wrote this question from the perspective of a beginner to make it useful for others and also to facilitate writing [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60586814/list-with-first-value-from-io/60586815#60586815).

Comment: In what language would the results of an analogous expression be cached?

Comment: Other languages don't have the concept of "IO actions" though, let alone of mapping over one. The nearest equivalent in most languages would be a function (impure of course) that waits for a second then returns a number - in which case if you make a list of such functions and run them in turn (which is essentially what you're doing) then again you would expect there to be a second's delay between each.

Comment: While it's *possible* to cache the return value of a pure function (though it's not done as often as you might hope, because there is considerable overhead involved in doing so), `slowOne` is *not* a function that happens to take a while to call the first time. It's an IO action, that *fundamentally* takes a long time to execute. The whole point of an IO action is to *not* cache the eventual result, otherwise actions like `getLine` would never return a different line each time you used it.

Comment: Somewhat related question, also involving expectations of "sharing" in `IO` actions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137468/how-to-implement-lazy-iterate-when-io-is-involved-in-haskell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the intuition you've developed (as described in your self-written [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60586814/list-with-first-value-from-io#60586815) to this question) is all that accurate.  Let me try to give you some better intuition.  You may also find [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51509020/7203016) helpful, though the question there was quite different.

In Haskell, a value of type `IO a` (for any type `a`, so an `IO Int` or an `IO String` or whatever) is sometimes referred to as an "IO action", but as @WillNess mentioned in a comment, it's best thought of as an "IO recipe".  For these recipes, we think of "evaluation" and "execution" as being completely separate operations.  *Evaluating* an expression of type `IO a` is like writing down the recipe.  The result of *evaluating* an expression of type `IO Int` is a value of type `IO Int`.  Producing this value performs no I/O and takes no time to speak of, even if the underlying I/O involves delays or other slow operations.  This evaluated `IO a` value can be passed around, stored, duplicated, modified, combined with other `IO` recipes, or completely ignored, all without performing any actual I/O.

In contrast, *executing* the resulting recipe is the process of actually performing the I/O operations.  The result of *executing* an `IO Int` is an `Int`.  If it involves 20 minutes of delays, file accesses, and/or carrier pigeon requisitioning to get that `Int`, the operation will take a while.  If you *execute* the same recipe twice, it won't go any faster the second time around.

Almost all of the code we write in Haskell *evaluates* IO recipes without executing them.

When the code:

```
slowOne = do
  threadDelay (10 ^ 6)
  return 1
```

is run, it actually just evaluates (writes down) an IO recipe.  Evaluating this recipe obviously involves evaluating a do-block.  This doesn't *do* the I/O; it just evaluates (writes down) each of the recipes in the do-block and combines them into a larger written recipe.

Specifically, evaluating `slowOne` involves:

1. Evaluating the recipe `threadDelay (10 ^ 6)`.  This involves evaluating the arithmetic expression `10 ^ 6` and calling the function `threadDelay` on it.  This function is implemented (for the non-threaded runtime) as:

   ```
    threadDelay :: Int -> IO ()
    threadDelay time = IO $ \s -> some_function_of_s
   ```

   That is, it wraps a function in an `IO` constructor to produce a value of type `IO ()`.  Critically, it doesn't actually delay the thread.  It just creates a (wrapped) functional value.  There's nothing magical about the `IO` constructor, by the way.  This `threadDelay` function is similar to writing the equally non-magical:

   ```
    justAFunction :: Int -> Maybe (Int -> Int)
    justAFunction c = Just (\x -> c*x)
   ```
2. Evaluating the recipe `return 1`.  This, too, just creates a value wrapped in an `IO` constructor.  Specifically, it's the (wrapped and completely non-magical) functional value that looks something like:

   ```
    IO (\s -> (s, 1))
   ```
3. Combining these two evaluated recipes sequentially into a longer recipe.  This new combined recipe is the value of type `IO Int` that will be assigned to `slowOne`.

Similarly, when the following code is evaluated:

```
infiniteInts :: [IO Integer]
infiniteInts = loop slowOne
  where
    loop :: IO Integer -> [IO Integer]
    loop ioInt = ioInt : loop (fmap (+1) ioInt)
```

you aren't executing any IO.  You're just evaluating IO recipes and data structures that contain IO recipes.  Specifically, you're evaluating this expression to a value of type `[IO Integer]` consisting of an infinite list of `IO Integer` values/recipes.  The first recipe in the list is `slowOne`.  The second recipe in the list is:

```
fmap (+1) slowOne
```

This requires a word of explanation.  When this expression is evaluated, it constructs a new recipe that could be written using an equivalent do-block:

```
fmap_plus_one_of_slowOne = do
  x <- slowOne
  return (x + 1)
```

Given how `slowOne` is defined, this is actually equivalent to the self-contained recipe we get by evaluating:

```
fmap_plus_one_of_slowOne = do
  threadDelay (10 ^ 6)
  return 2
```

Similarly, the third recipe on the list:

```
fmap (+1) (fmap (+1) slowOne)
```

evaluates to the equivalent of the recipe:

```
fmap_plus_one_of_fmap_plus_one_of_slowOne = do
  threadDelay (10 ^ 6)
  return 3
```

Now, the last part of your program is:

```
mapM_
    (\ioInt -> do
      i <- ioInt
      print i
    )
  infiniteInts
```

It might surprise you to hear that, when this code is evaluated, we're **still** only *evaluating* and not *executing* recipes.  When this `mapM_` function is evaluated, it constructs a new recipe.  The recipe it constructs could be described in words as:

> "Take each recipe in the list `infiniteInts`.  Sorry about the bad choice of name -- this isn't a list of integers, but a list of IO *recipes* for making integers.  It's a good thing you're a computer and won't get confused by this, huh?  Anyway, take each of those recipes in sequence and pass them to this function I have here to generate a new recipe.  Then, run that list of recipes in order.  You're writing this down, right?  Stop, don't *execute* anything yet!  Just write it down!"

So, let's recap:

- `slowOne` is the recipe

  ```
  do threadDelay (10 ^ 6)
     return 1
  ```
- `fmap (+1) slowOne` is the same as the recipe:

  ```
  do threadDelay (10 ^ 6)
     return 2
  ```
- similarly, `fmap (+1) (fmap (+1) slowOne)` is really just the recipe

  ```
  do threadDelay (10 ^ 6)
     return 3
  ```

  and so on
- therefore, `infiniteInts` is the list of recipes:

  ```
  infiniteInts =
    [ do { threadDelay (10 ^ 6); return 1 }
    , do { threadDelay (10 ^ 6); return 2 }
    , do { threadDelay (10 ^ 6); return 3 }
    , ... ]
  ```

Given the meaning of the `mapM_ ...` recipe, if Haskell allowed infinitely long programs, we could have written this entire recipe from scratch as follows:

```
do   -- first recipe
     threadDelay (10 ^ 6)
     i <- return 1
     print i

     -- second recipe
     threadDelay (10 ^ 6)
     i <- return 2
     print i

     -- third recipe
     threadDelay (10 ^ 6)
     i <- return 3
     print i

     -- etc.
```

That's the recipe that results from evaluating the `mapM_ ...` expression.

Finally, then, we get to the **only part of your program** that executes an IO recipe rather than simply evaluating it.  That part is:

```
main = ...
```

When you name a recipe `main`, you tell Haskell to execute it when the program is run.  As you can see from the evaluated value of the recipe you've assigned to `main`, it's a combined recipe involving interleaved `threadDelay` and `print` recipes, so when it's executed, it prints an increasing list of integers with delays before each integer.

A note on laziness versus strictness...  Laziness plays no role in the process above (well, except for allowing us to construct an infinite list without locking up the machine).  When I say "evaluate" above, it makes no difference whether the evaluation is strict and occurs immediately or if the evaluation is technically delayed until it's needed.  The point at which it's needed *might* be when it's being executed, but the evaluation (writing of the recipe) and execution (following the recipe) are still distinct processes, even if they occur one right after the other.

Comment: [cf.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60586814/list-with-first-value-from-io#comment107259707_60593573)

Comment: I wish all monad answers where like that!

Answer (score 0):

## Warning:

This answer is incorrect with regards to running expressions. Refer to [K. A. Buhr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60586814/list-with-first-value-from-io#60623166) first to get a better understanding of how this list of IO values works.

---

We can understand this behavior by

- rewriting the recursive function
- keeping in mind that GHC [doesn't cache results from IO](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258663/how-can-io-cause-side-effects-in-functional-programming#answer-258668)

Here are the rewritings of `infiniteInts` for getting different numbers of elements:

### Getting one element

```
slowOne : loop (fmap (+1) slowOne)
```

Since Haskell's `:` operator is non-strict, we run `slowOne` once → this takes one second.

### Getting two elements

```
slowOne : (fmap (+1) slowOne) : loop (fmap (+1) (fmap (+1) slowOne))
```

Taking two elements (up till the second `:`) causes `slowOne` to be called twice → this takes two seconds.

### Getting three elements

```
slowOne : (fmap (+1) slowOne) : (fmap (+1) (fmap (+1) slowOne)) : loop (fmap (+1) (fmap (+1) (fmap (+1) slowOne)))
```

Taking three elements (up till the third `:`) causes `slowOne` to be called three times → this takes three seconds.

### Summary

From the rewritings we can see that `slowOne` is called for each element (e.g., three times for three elements) and given that GHC won't cache results created inside IO (which is the case for `slowOne`) it follows that each element takes a second to be created.

Comment: It might be useful to contrast it with code that will delay only for the first element

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that IO actions are *never* cached; it's not just an optimization that GHC (or any there implementation) chooses not to perform. An IO action is *fundamentally* something that, by design, is executed in full each time it is executed.

Comment: "Since Haskell's `:` operator is non-strict, we evaluate slowOne once" **no**. there is no evaluation at all (in the IO sense which you intended, I assume) there. `slowOne` is just a regular pure Haskell value of type `IO Integer`. Making a list of `n` of them is just a list of `n` pure Haskell values. No IO "evaluation" in sight yet. each `slowOne` value is like a separate program. `mapM_` combines all these programs into one program that will do them in sequence (`mapM` would also collects their results in a list) *when* it runs. each program (the same one) does what it said it would: delay.

Answer (score 0):

Every number is delayed because they're all coming from `slowOne`. Consider your `loop`:

```
loop ioInt = ioInt : loop (fmap (+1) ioInt)
     ^----This is slowOne              ^
                                       └----This is also slowOne
```

My own intuition about what it is that your `fmap` is doing is simply acting on the IO value (the `Integer` in `IO Integer`), but keeping all of its context (the "IO" part) intact.

As Will Ness's commented:

> `fmap (1+)` takes an IO value (a pure value of type IO t for some t) which describes I/O action that will return a pure value `x :: t` when that action will run; and creates a new pure IO value describing an augmented I/O action that will return the pure value `x+1` after performing the I/O actions as described by the first IO value.

As an example of this, we could replace `slowOne` by another function `timedOne`:

```
timedOne = do
  time <- getPOSIXTime
  putStrLn $ "time: " ++ show time
  return 1
```

Calling `loop` with `timedOne` instead of `slowOne` would print this out, showing how `fmap` affects the value without affecting the context:

```
time: 1583715559.051068s
1
time: 1583715559.051705s
2
time: 1583715559.052311s
3
... and so on
```

You see that each number that gets used, still carries its own IO "baggage", only this time that baggage is "get the time from the system clock and print it out". If you want to change this behaviour so that only the first number will be delayed, you need to purge the tail of the list built by `loop` of any thread-delaying IO baggage. One way to do that is by using a pure list and wrapping each element in IO:

```
loop ioInt = ioInt : (return <$> [2..])
```

Comment: no. `fmap (1+)` is not "simply taking the IO value returned by action". `fmap (1+)` takes an IO value (a pure value of type `IO t` for some `t`)  which describes I/O action that will `return` a pure value `x :: t` when that action will run; and creates a new pure IO value describing an augmented I/O action that will `return` the pure value `x+1` after performing the I/O actions as described by the first IO value. the values and the actions they describe are separate things. the new vogue is to refer to those pure IO values (once referred to as "actions", which is confusing) as "recipes".

Comment: Thank you @WillNess. I added a note in my answer referring to your comment, as I think my original answer still gave a good *intuition* of about was happening, and that is what OP was looking for.

Comment: I would be extremely confused by that wording if I hadn't already have my current understanding of this. in fact I *was* getting extremely confused by exactly that kind of wording, before I came to my current understanding. :)

Comment: (and saw on SO recently an even better one than "recipe": it is ... ["an instruction"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60547173/849891)!)